# Automated daily summary of top stories from Google Reader?

Tags: google-reader

I love Google Reader, but am tiring of constant, all day long updates. Does anyone know of a way to get an automated list of the top stories from all my feeds, by number of links or some other statistic, so at the end of each day I can see a news paper like report on the days most important stories to appear in my feeds?

Answer (score 2):

If you change "View Settings" (or "Folder Settings" for a particular folder) to "Sort by magic", GReader will pull to the top the items it thinks you'll be most interested in, based on your past activity. (What you've read, clicked on, etc.)